# why there is no RequestMappingHandlerMapping in DispatcherServlet.properties?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

As far as I know, *DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping* is deprecated in favor of *RequestMappingHandlerMapping*. However, *DispatcherServlet.properties* in spring-webmvc-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar looks like that:

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping=org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping
```

So, it does not contain new *RequestMappingHandlerMapping*. It only contains old, deprecated *DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping*.

Why?

Comment: Please go through this [link](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/01/spring-mvc-customizing-requestmappinghandlermapping.html), it may answer your query.

Comment: I asked (more or less) the same question 4 years ago, [here](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-8721). It is intentional...